# How to get text from word document into a string using vb?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-word

can anyone teach me how to get text from Microsoft Word using vb code?

Comment: I removed the encryption part of your question, because it doesn't have anything to do with the first part of the question. If you get this solved, then you can use your favorite search engine to look how you can apply encryption.

Comment: We could help if you showed us what you have tried...

Comment: There are many examples of doing so here, as well as in search results from Google. While we're glad to help here, we expect you to put in at least a reasonable effort to find a solution yourself first. Failing to even do a simple search is not making a reasonable effort.

Comment: im sorry thats my bad.. actually i just want to know what thing i need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a tested example of a simple function to return the text from a word document given its filepath, hope this helps:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim docfilepath As String = "C:\Users\sooho\Desktop\test.docx"
    Dim doctext As String = getDocText(docfilepath)
    If doctext IsNot Nothing Then MsgBox(doctext)
    Me.Close()
End Sub
Private Function getDocText(ByVal filepath As String) As String
    If File.Exists(filepath) AndAlso Path.GetExtension(filepath).ToUpper.Equals(".DOCX") Then
        Dim app As Application = New Application
        Dim doc As Document = app.Documents.Open(filepath)
        Dim doctxt As String = doc.Content.Text
        app.Quit()
        Return doctxt
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

EDIT: forgot to mention, you will need to add Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word framework as a reference in your project's settings, this is required to interact with any word document unless you're using a third-party library. Also, not shown, "Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word" and "Imports System.IO" are needed at the beginning of your code for this example to compile.

Comment: Why did you add this when you don't use it: `Dim ext As String = Path.GetExtension(filepath)`?

Comment: Oops...I put that line there so I could set a break point and check path.getextension's return, and then forgot to take it back out, good eye...I'll strip it out

Comment: thank you @soohoonigan, its very helpfull, ill learn more about Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386277.aspx)  **its solved thx**